# Elpy auto-complete gives incomplete suggestions

Tags: python, auto-complete-mode, elpy, jedi

I am trying to use Elpy for Emacs to write Python programs.  The
auto-complete feature suggests all attributes of PyQt5 classes, but
suggests only a subset of the attributes of instances of these
classes.

All attributes of the class QLabel are suggested when I type this in Emacs:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
app = QApplication([])
label = QLabel()
QLabel.
```

However, if I replace the last line with:

```
label.
```

then only a small subset of the attributes are suggested.  (The
missing attributes include those marked as "module" when I type
`QLabel.`  For example the method `getText()` is missing.)  This is
strange because Elpy (or company or jedi?) clearly knows the type of
`label` to be able to suggest a subset of its attributes!

I am using a fresh install of kubuntu 18.04, with Emacs 25 and Python
3 installed from packages, and follow the [Installation instructions
for
Elpy](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#installation).

```
apt install python3 python3-pip emacs
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

I use a virtual environment called `elpy` with these packages installed:

```
(elpy) prompt$ pip list
Package     Version
----------- -------
appdirs     1.4.3  
attrs       19.1.0 
autopep8    1.4.3  
black       19.3b0 
Click       7.0    
entrypoints 0.3    
flake8      3.7.7  
jedi        0.13.3 
mccabe      0.6.1  
parso       0.3.4  
pip         19.0.3 
pycodestyle 2.5.0  
pyflakes    2.1.1  
PyQt5       5.12.1 
PyQt5-sip   4.19.15
rope        0.14.0 
setuptools  40.8.0 
toml        0.10.0 
wheel       0.33.1 
yapf        0.26.0
```

Here is my `.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(elpy-enable)
(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (elpy))))
(custom-set-faces)
```

Output from `elpy-config`:

```
Virtualenv........: elpy (/home/asbuch/lib/virtualenvs/elpy)
RPC Python........: 3.6.7 (/home/asbuch/lib/virtualenvs/elpy/bin/python)
Interactive Python: python (/home/asbuch/lib/virtualenvs/elpy/bin/python)
Emacs.............: 25.2.2
Elpy..............: 1.28.0
Jedi..............: 0.13.3
Rope..............: 0.14.0
Autopep8..........: 1.4.3
Yapf..............: 0.26.0
Black.............: 19.3b0
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/asbuch/lib/virtualenvs/elpy/bin/flake8)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!